# I would like to know which browsers support HTTP Push

Tags: push, server-push

I am looking for a list of browsers that support HTTP Push.

I've looked around and I cannot find that list.

I know that Firefox, Webkit, Opera support it... But what about IE?

Also what version of those browsers support it?

Comment: Might be worth clarifying if you only want HTTP mechanisms or if you just want the Browser Push functionality. HTTP restricts the transport mechanism to HTTP Polling, HTTP Long-Polling and HTTP Streaming. Most solutions will use WebSockets were possible now.

Comment: Ok So if I understand this correctly they are different ways to have HTTP PUSH. One with Long-Polling and the second one is with WebSockets...

Comment: Not quite. There are different ways to be able to push data from a web server to a browser. The first is using HTTP. The techniques available are [HTTP Long-Polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling) and [HTTP Streaming](http://www.quora.com/HTTP-Streaming). WebSockets is a newer technology that beings life as an HTTP connection but is then upgraded to a WebSocket connection. Read more about WebSockets [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and [here](http://pusher.com/websockets).

Answer (score 1):

As for [Socket.io](http://socket.io) library, supported browsers are listed [here](http://socket.io/#browser-support). If you are interested in Websocket support, take a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support).

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit confused... Is there different types of HTTP PUSH?